# VS 2008 web services generating wrong url

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-services

Haven't done much web service development so this is probably an easy fix. Created both a mobile device project and web service project. When I add the service to my mobile project the soap document method attribute is wrong. All other info is correct. It generates service/method when it should actually be service?op= method. it will not work unless I manually change this url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing the URL you are using from http://whatevertoyourwebservice.asmx to http://localhost/whateverwebservice.asmx  If you have the ability to use localhost this will work without having to change the url in the app.config folder.  the other way is to use JavaScript to call your web service.

Here is an example is use for UTCTime webservice:

```
var portalUrl = window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf('/', 8));
var serviceUrl = portalUrl + "/your_webservice_location/";


var utcTimeOffsets = [];

function GetUtcOffsets(timezones, func) {


var proxy = new ServiceProxy(serviceUrl);
proxy.isWcf = false;
proxy.invoke("GetUTCOffsets",
    { tzName: timezones },
    function(result) {
                   utcTimeOffsets = result;

        if (func) func();


    },
    function(error, i, request) {
        alert(error);
        //setTimeout(function() { GetUTC(location) }, 1000);
    },
    false);
```

}

Other then that there is going to be no way, that I have found anyways, to make the C# webservice call dynamic.  If you find a way please let me know.  I know that these two options will work.